# Backing PDF files and SQL server DB

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, sql-server, backup, sql-server-2008

I have my own Windows Server an Asp.Net application hosted live. The application allows users to upload CV PDF files and I have the DB also on that server. Which steps should I take to ensure that all data is there all the time even in case of hard drive failure?

I know RAID5 can be done but I only want to backup certain folders on my hard drive. I have heard of SQL server replication which would prevent the data loss in case of hard drive failure.

Which tactics are you using for this purpose on your server?

Thanks.

Comment: If your hard drive fails, your OS won't work, right?

Answer (score 2):

"even in case of hard drive failure" - Use RAID
... but what if the server implodes?

If you want an always on soulution, look at a cluster. In the same cluster you can store both the SQL and all files.

btw, Backup! Whatever way you go... you can never (ehm, well..) recover from an admin fault (does a delete instead of an update) without a proper backup.